# useEffect with async functions works at the second render, but not the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a Weather app with React Native.

```
//States
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
```

```
//useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  requestLocationPermission();
}, []);
```

These are my 3 async functions:

```
//Getting location permission
const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    console.log('requestLocationPermission started');
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        );
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          console.log('You can use the location');
          getLocation();
        } else {
          console.log('Location permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
      console.log('requestLocationPermission finished');
    };

//Getting Location
const getLocation = async () => {
    console.log('getLocation started');
    try {
      await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        setLocation(position);
        console.log(position);
        getWeather();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Err:' + err);
    }
    console.log('getLocation finished');
  };

  const getWeather = async () => {
    console.log('getWeather started');
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${location['coords']['latitude']}&lon=${location['coords']['longitude']}&appid=${WEATHER_API_KEY}`,
        ).then(response => response.json());
        console.log('response');
        console.log(response);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Err:' + err);
      }
      console.log('getWeather finished');
  };
```

I grant permission from the simulator. And I get the location obviously. But surprisingly I cannot send the API request because I do not get the data from the location.

After rendering a second time, the API call works. I cannot get the reason.

This is the console after the first render:

```
info Reloading app...
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

 LOG  Running "WeatherApp" with {"rootTag":331}
 LOG  requestLocationPermission started
 LOG  You can use the location
 LOG  getLocation started
 LOG  requestLocationPermission finished
 LOG  getLocation finished
 LOG  {"coords": {"accuracy": 600, "altitude": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": 37.4220936, "longitude": -122.083922, "speed": 0}, "extras": {"networkLocationType": "cell"}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1682430365994}
 LOG  getWeather started
 LOG  Err:TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of null
 LOG  getWeather finished
```

This is the console after the second rendering:

```
info Reloading app...
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

 LOG  Running "WeatherApp" with {"rootTag":331}
 LOG  requestLocationPermission started
 LOG  You can use the location
 LOG  getLocation started
 LOG  requestLocationPermission finished
 LOG  getLocation finished
 LOG  {"coords": {"accuracy": 600, "altitude": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": 37.4220936, "longitude": -122.083922, "speed": 0}, "extras": {"networkLocationType": "cell"}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1682430365994}
 LOG  getWeather started
 LOG  Err:TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of null
 LOG  getWeather finished
 LOG  requestLocationPermission started
 LOG  You can use the location
 LOG  getLocation started
 LOG  requestLocationPermission finished
 LOG  getLocation finished
 LOG  {"coords": {"accuracy": 600, "altitude": 0, "heading": 0, "latitude": 37.4220936, "longitude": -122.083922, "speed": 0}, "extras": {"networkLocationType": "cell"}, "mocked": false, "timestamp": 1682432167007}
 LOG  getWeather started
 LOG  response
 LOG  {"base": "stations", "clouds": {"all": 0}, "cod": 200, "coord": {"lat": 37.4221, "lon": -122.0839}, "dt": 1682431628, "id": 5375480, "main": {"feels_like": 281.24, "humidity": 85, "pressure": 1013, "temp": 281.82, "temp_max": 284, "temp_min": 280.34}, "name": "Mountain View", "sys": {"country": "US", "id": 2010364, "sunrise": 1682428825, "sunset": 1682477513, "type": 2}, "timezone": -25200, "visibility": 10000, "weather": [{"description": "mist", "icon": "50d", "id": 701, "main": "Mist"}], "wind": {"deg": 180, "speed": 1.54}}
 LOG  getWeather finished
```

Comment: Many ways to go around this. You could pass position to getWeather function and use it instead of location state. But if you want to use the location state, you should call getWeather in a useEffect with location state as dependency.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar I used location state and refactored the code as what your recommend. useEffect triggered infinitely. After I put (if(location ) return ) in the getWeather() it works properly. Thank you.

Comment: You've to add location in the dependency array and add a condition to check if location is not null/undefined.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar makes good points. I posted a detailed answer on why it's like this in the first place. Check it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

When you call a state setter and try using that state right after, you get the old value, As the [doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats) says:

> The `set` function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the `set` function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

This is your problem as you are calling `getWeather()` just after `setLocation(position)`.

## Solutions

The easiest way to tackle this, which wouldn't change your code much, is to pass `position` to `getWeather` as a parameter, like so:

```
await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  setLocation(position);
  getWeather(position);
});
```

And update `getWeather` to use the position passed as an argument and not the one coming from the outside:

```
function getWeather(passedPosition){
 // Use passedPosition instead position from the outside.
}
```

Or remove that `getWeather()` after `setLocation(position)` inside `getCurrentPosition`, and have it in a separate `useEffect`, like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(!position) return;
  getWeather()
},[position])
```